# Completed the RHCE - what next?

Tags: linux

So I've completed the [RHCE](http://www.redhat.com/certification/rhce/) exam last week, and all went well. Not bad for a Debian geek!

My employer is keen on continuing my certification, and is open to ideas. So my question is what tests do people recommened? I understand the RHCE is the defacto test, but is it worth continuting down the same path to towards to the [RHCA](http://www.redhat.com/certification/rhca/) collecting the specialized Redhat exams - or progressing out, perhaps to other tests?

I might as well make the most of the offer, so what do people think?

Answer (score 5):

Although you don't specify your other skills, [MySQL Certification](http://www.mysql.com/certification/) has historically gone down well on CVs and isn't that widespread - dependent on your situtaion there are four separate certs:

- CMA: Certified MySQL Associate
- CMDEV: Certified MySQL Developer
- CMDBA: Certified MySQL Database Administrator
- CMCDBA: Certified MySQL Cluster Database Administrator

I assume you'd want the third one. Progression with RH is also of benefit, it really depends on your career aspirations. Where do you see yourself in 5 years? Do a course to get you there :)

Answer (score 4):

It's not a certification, but I highly, highly, *highly* recommend reading "The Practice of System and Network Administration." It's all about the transferrable skills you'll need to possess for any admin job, regardless of what technology you will use. Soft skills, proceedures and best practices, mindsets, and What Not To Do. There's even stuff in there about management of <strike>kittens</strike> admins if your career gets to that point.

Technical study is important, but knowing about Change Management and why everyone should have a trouble ticket system is even moreso.

I also recommend "Time Management for Sysadmins". For completely different reasons.

Comment: +1! TPSNA should be required reading for everyone who calls them self an admin of anything. I never read TMS, but am influenced by David Allen for the better. Time management is needed for everyone, but I think especially admins.

Answer (score 1):

If I were going down the certification route, I'd look at things that tie-in logically: A+, MySQL, CISCO, Network+, etc.

Might even throw-in the MSCE just so you're "well-rounded".

Comment: Yeah, well-rounded...  Like the job postings looking for 20 years of Server 2000 experience.  I do agree that tangentially related certs are good but don't get an MCSE just to get one.  I'm considering it in my current role because we are mixed 60/40 windows right now.  I have a few friends that have gone further in the RH certification route and have enjoyed it but I can't vouch for any improvement in pay or position.  I'd say go with what interests you and fits with what the company wants (either this one or the next one).  Good luck and congrats.

Comment: If you've already got an RHCE, I wouldn't bother with any cert that ends with +. They tend to be far closer to entry level certification, than the RHCE. CCNA might be worth doing though.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to do. Do you want to specialize or be a generalist with deep knowledge in several areas? Do you want to focus on internal system administration or Internet-facing system administration? Do you care for administration or architecting of systems?

If you want to pursue a well-rounded education aimed at web hosting, for example, I would recommend pursuing MySQL/Oracle expertise, a web-oriented programming language forte (PHP, ruby, Java -- has actual certification track, etc.), Cisco certification track, and security certification.

Nothing, however, beats doing the work and having a proven, demonstratable skill set. However, your question is about employer-sponsored certification tracks, specifically, and not marketability. I assume you will put in use what you learn and are certified in -- that will make it worthwhile to your employer and to YOU! Which brings us back to my first paragraph: it really depends on what **you** want to do.

Comment: Yeah, I know it comes down to myself really, but there is not a lot of immediate information on what certification in relation to Linux is actually useful or desired. I'm tempted by the MySQL certification mentioned in the post above as they have a broad application with a strong technical interest.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the LPI certifications, generally known as LPIC1 and 2. They are distro independent and make a lot of sense to me. Seeing that you have RHCE, you should theoretically be able to just sit the exams, at least for LPIC1.

Comment: I actually tried to LPI-1 when I was about 16 (it was pretty new then) - failed by a few marks. It was "distro independent" then, but two pages of using the RPM command stumped me! Also doesn't it lack the practical side which a lot of the high-level tests reply on?

Answer (score 1):

Any Security certification. e.g. CISSP

Cheers